# Filter nested array using projection without using unwind

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, dynamodb-queries, nosql-aggregation

I have my collection1 which holds the _ids of collection2 in projects field as follows:

```
    {
        "name": "adafd",
        "employeeId": "employeeId",
        "locations": [
            "ObjectId(adfaldjf)",
            "ObjectId(adfaldjf)",
            "ObjectId(adfaldjf)",
            "ObjectId(adfaldjf)",
            "ObjectId(adfaldjf)",
            "ObjectId(adfaldjf)"
        ]
    }
```

collection2 is as follows

```
"collection2": [
    {   
        "location": "india",
        "states": [
            {
                "stateCode": "TN",
                    "districts": {
                        "cities": [
                            {
                                "code": 1,
                                "name": "xxx"
                            },
                            {
                                "code": 4,
                                "name": "zzz"
                            },
                            {
                                "code": 6,
                                "name": "yyy"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I am trying to filter nested arrays inside collection2 after lookup as follows:

```
    db.collection.aggregate([
        {
            $lookup: {
                from: "collection2",
                localField: "locations",
                foreignField: "_id",
                as: "locations"
            }
        },
        {
            $match: {
                "name": "adafd",
            },
        },
        {
            $project: {
                'details': {
                    $filter: {
                        input: "$locations",
                        as: "location",
                        cond: { 
                            "$eq": ["$$location.states.stateCode", "TN" ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
)
```

It is returning an empty array for `locations`.

I modified the project as follows to even filter states inside collection2 array in the projection as follows, but filters are not applying. It is returning all the data inside the `states` array.

```
{
        $project: {
            'details': {
                $filter: {
                    input: "$locations",
                    as: "location",
                    cond: { 
                        $filter: {
                            input: "$location.states",
                            as: "state",
                            cond: { 
                                "$eq": ["$$state.stateCode", "TN" ]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I have found several solutions regarding this but none worked for me. As I don't want to use unwind. Is there any way to achieve this..?

Note: I don't want to use **pipeline** inside **$lookup** as it is not supported by DocumentDB. And also there should be any **$unwind** and **$group** in the query.

Comment: there is no `location` field in collection1, what is in the $match stage `{ "location": "india" }`?

Comment: It is just random data. I have changed location to name

Comment: ok, can you add the expected result.

Comment: Only thing is I should be able to filter nested arrays and all the oprators used in the query should also work in DocumentDB

Comment: there is confusion, you want to filter states and location both? or only location?

Comment: I want to filter based on location, states and also cities

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- `$match` your conditions
- `$lookup` with collection2
- `$project` to filter `locations` by location name
- `$unwind` deconstruct the `locations` array
- `$project` to filter `states` by state code
- `$unwind` deconstruct the `states` array
- `$project` to filter `cities` by city code
- `$unwind` deconstruct the `cities` array

```
db.collection1.aggregate([
  { $match: { name: "adafd" } },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "collection2",
      localField: "locations",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "locations"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      locations: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$locations",
          cond: { $eq: ["$$this.location", "india"] }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { $unwind: "$locations" },
  {
    $project: {
      locations: {
        _id: "$locations._id",
        location: "$locations.location",
        states: {
          $filter: {
            input: "$locations.states",
            cond: { $eq: ["$$this.stateCode", "TN"] }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { $unwind: "$locations.states" },
  {
    $project: {
      locations: {
        _id: "$locations._id",
        location: "$locations.location",
        states: {
          stateCode: "$locations.states.stateCode",
          districts: {
            cities: {
              $filter: {
                input: "$locations.states.districts.cities",
                cond: { $eq: ["$$this.code", 1] }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { $unwind: "$locations.states.districts.cities" }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/fc0HJO20OXJ)

---

Second option without using `$unwind`, instead of you can use `$arrayElemAt`,

```
db.collection1.aggregate([
  { $match: { name: "adafd" } },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "collection2",
      localField: "locations",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "locations"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      locations: {
        $arrayElemAt: [
          {
            $filter: {
              input: "$locations",
              cond: { $eq: ["$$this.location", "india"] }
            }
          },
          0
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      locations: {
        _id: "$locations._id",
        location: "$locations.location",
        states: {
          $arrayElemAt: [
            {
              $filter: {
                input: "$locations.states",
                cond: { $eq: ["$$this.stateCode", "TN"] }
              }
            },
            0
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      locations: {
        _id: "$locations._id",
        location: "$locations.location",
        states: {
          stateCode: "$locations.states.stateCode",
          districts: {
            cities: {
              $arrayElemAt: [
                {
                  $filter: {
                    input: "$locations.states.districts.cities",
                    cond: { $eq: ["$$this.code", 1] }
                  }
                },
                0
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/QEcLFr7sng7)

Answer (score 2):

You might use `$map`. There are several mistakes in your code. `$match` needs to be `"locations.location":"india"` and inside the `filter input` you need to use `$$<var name>`

```
db.collection1.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "collection2",
      localField: "locations",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "locations"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      "details": {
        input: {
          $map: {
            input: "$locations",
            as: "location",
            in: {
              "_id": "$$location._id",
              location: "$$location.location",
              states: {
                $filter: {
                  input: "$$location.states",
                  as: "state",
                  cond: {
                    "$eq": [
                      "$$state.stateCode",
                      "TN"
                    ]
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

**Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/h-GW8HIlsap)**

Suppose if you need to eliminate documents which hold empty state, you can easily do with `match`

Comment: is map operator inside projection supported by DocumentDB. Because it is a variable operator. I think it is not supported in DocumentDB

Comment: Most of the operators are not supported by DocumentDB. I had this issue, so I gave up migrating to DocumentDB

Comment: Is there any other way to achieve the required result with the operators which are supported by DocumentDB

Comment: I will try, most of the important operator are not supported. I advise you not to look into the temporary solution, Sometimes you need more operators in future. then you will be facing difficulties. There is another solution, you can get the documents after the lookup stage and do you work programmatically using for loops and if conditions

Comment: how to apply a filter for location inside map i.e location should be equal to india

Comment: use `match` https://mongoplayground.net/p/JK7NliDzkxY

Answer (score -1):

You can try it like this Its working

```
db.getCollection('col').aggregate([
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "col",
            localField: "locations",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "locations"
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            'locations': {
                $filter: {
                    input: "$collection2",
                    as: "collection",
                    cond: { 
                        "$eq": ["$$collection.location", "india" ],
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            'details': {
                $filter: {
                    input: "$locations",
                    as: "location",
                    cond: { 
                        $filter: {
                            input: "$$location.states",
                            as: "state",
                            cond: { 
                                "$eq": ["$$state.stateCode", "TN" ]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
])
```